# Decoding Russian ISS telemetry

Tags: iss, communication, russia

While the American segment of the ISS has data published on-line (http://spacestationlive.nasa.gov), the same cannot be said about the Russian segment.

It is known that telemetry is transmitted to the Earth on 128 kHz-wide PCM ([Pulse-code modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCM)) FM ([Frequency modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation)) channels at 628, 630, 632, 634, 922, 928 MHz (source: http://www.ea1uro.com/megasat.html).

- How could one receive, demodulate, and decode the telemetry?
- Is Russian ISS telemetry encrypted?
- Are there any high-frequency data items in the frames (transmitted more often than once a second - 1 Hz).

Historical reference: [Sven Grahn's Space Radio page](http://www.svengrahn.pp.se/radioind/radioin1.htm).

Comment: When you'll get your hands on the data, double check what you have really got. There's an anecdote about a fake telemetry provided to ESA. The data kept coming even after the station has been deorbited. http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.airbase.ru%2F2013%2F05%2Ft80734--falshivaya-telemetriya-mira.8230.html

Comment: @horsh - fodder for Skeptics.SE (an urban legend or a myth), I'm afraid. Folks from ESOC need to chime in on this.

Comment: RAX-2 telemetry decoder is the software that can do your work
http://rax.engin.umich.edu/?page_id=882

http://www.pe0sat.vgnet.nl/2013/telemetry-decoding/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RAX-2 telemetry decoder](http://rax.engin.umich.edu/?page_id=882) is the software that can do your work

Tutorial/How to use: 
[pe0sat.vgnet.nl/2013/telemetry-decoding](http://pe0sat.vgnet.nl/2013/telemetry-decoding)

Comment: To prevent link rot, you can expand your answer and include the most relevant bits from your experience and linked documents into the question.

Comment: http://www.uhf-satcom.com/sband/

Comment: The russian segment uses Regul-OS as a command system, BITS2-12, and BR-9TsU-3 as telemetry systems. In general, the answer should be fleshed out much more.

Comment: While these two links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid, if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link http://rax.engin.umich.edu/?page_id=882 has apparently rotted: "The server at rax.engin.umich.edu is taking too long to respond."